# How does the presence of routerLinkActive cause a mat-row to be focused

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is not really an issue, just trying to understand behavior better.

I have a `mat-table` which I had been handling `click` events from to highlight rows, and I'm switching now to make it work with a `router` instead.

When I add `routerLinkActive` to a `mat-row` and then click on the row it becomes highlighted. It turns out this is due to `:focus` being set for some reason which causes a blue outline.

```
<mat-row 
        matRipple

        routerLink="doesnt/exist"
        routerLinkActive="class-doesnt-even-exist"

        *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
        (click)="alert('clicked')"></mat-row>
```

It isn't even an active route that is being highlighted, just the row I click on.

The docs for `mat-table` even says the following:

> mat-table does not manage any focus/keyboard interaction on its own.
>   Users can add desired focus/keyboard interactions in their
>   application.

I've looked in the source for [the router directives](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/5.2.4/packages/router/src/directives) and don't see anything there about focus.

The problem can easily be solved by setting my own `:focus` selector, but I'm trying to understand what is causing this out of curiosity.

Here's a sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-generic-data-table-mzro7w?file=app/data-table/data-table.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it looks like it's down to `tabindex`.

The constructor for router_link does the following

```
constructor(
      private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,
      @Attribute('tabindex') tabIndex: string, renderer: Renderer2, el: ElementRef) {
    if (tabIndex == null) {
      renderer.setAttribute(el.nativeElement, 'tabindex', '0');
    }
  }
```

So you have to set tabIndex="-1" if you have a mat-table and you don't want each row to be a tab stop. There may be cases where you want this, but for me I want a grid that acts like a single entity  that isn't tabbable.

So now I have this:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: selectedColumns;"
         matRipple
         routerLink="order/{{ row.orderId }}"
         routerLinkActive="highlighted"
         tabindex="-1"
         (click)="clicked(row)"></mat-row>
```

In addition you still need to add this css to prevent the outline (tabindex even when set to -1 allows the browser to set focus on the element when clicked or right clicked):

```
.mat-row:focus
{
   outline: none;
}
```

It seems that this behavior was [added Dec 2016](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10895) but wasn't made optional.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `tabindex="-1"` there are some downfalls.  You can no longer focus any child element inside there.  Taking a look at [the sourcecode for RouterLink](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8793dbd8a20e368e6254fbcf78c7cdf505e37cc7/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L199) we can see that Angular is looking for the presence of any tabindex attribute and if one exists, it will not monkey with the tabindex.

My solution then was to use `tabindex="ignore"` -- an intentionally invalid value.  In practice, we get the best of both worlds: Angular does not add the tabindex attribute, and child elements can still be focused if they have tabindex, and the browser ignores the invalid value and doesn't consider it a tab stop.